# How can I use this mysql query to laravel 5.2?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to use below sql query into laravel 5.2

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE soundex(`products`.`name`)=soundex('Neckholder Creme');
```

I Have tried here like

```
return $query->select([ 'products.slug', 'products.id', 'sku', 'name', 'regular_price', 'sale_price', 'sale_from', 'sale_to', 'stock_status', 'product_type', 'featured_image_id' ])
            ->with('media_featured_image')
            ->with('categories')
            ->where('products.product_type', '<>', 'variation')
            ->where('products.status',  'publish')
            ->where(function($query) use ($keyword){
                foreach($keyword as $k){
                    $query->where('soundex(products.name)',soundex($k));
                }
            })
            ->paginate(120);
```

But it gives an error like below and having issue because of `` in column name

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'soundex(products.name)' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `products` where exists (select * from `categories` inner join `category_product` on `categories`.`id` = `category_product`.`category_id` where `category_product`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` and `categories`.`slug` <> shoparchiv) and `products`.`product_type` <> variation and `products`.`status` = publish and (`soundex(products`.`name)` = C352 and `soundex(products`.`name)` = J520))
```

How can I use in Laravel ? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need just basic query then you can use `DB::raw`  ([documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#selects))

```
select(DB::raw('SELECT * FROM products WHERE soundex(products.name)=soundex("Neckholder Creme")'));
```

Or you can use `whereRaw` in eloquent and use it in your existing query ([documentaion](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#advanced-where-clauses))

```
return $query->select([ 'products.slug', 'products.id', 'sku', 'name', 'regular_price', 'sale_price', 'sale_from', 'sale_to', 'stock_status', 'product_type', 'featured_image_id' ])
            ->with('media_featured_image')
            ->with('categories')
            ->where('products.product_type', '<>', 'variation')
            ->where('products.status',  'publish')
            ->where(function($query) use ($keyword){
                foreach($keyword as $k){
                    $query->whereRaw("soundex(products.name) = '".soundex($k)."'");
                }
            })
            ->paginate(120);
```

Hope it helps